# Linux pings from VM on virtual bridge get sent, but not returned

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bridge, linux-kvm

I'm setting up a virtual bridge on my laptop, so I can connect multiple VMs to it as a virtual lab environment. I want my laptop to route packets from the bridge to my actual network interface so the VMs have internet access. I don't want the network interface itself to be bridged.

To that end, I've set up a bridge called vmnet and given it an IP address.

```
5: vmnet: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:3a:11:0f:b1:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/24 scope global vmnet
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have `dnsmasq` set up to listen on that bridge and hand out IP addresses to those VMs ranging from 172.20.0.100 to 172.20.0.150.

To get the routing going, I enabled IPv4 forwarding in the kernel:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

On the host machine, I can ping other devices in the network, for example my router and my raspberry pi:

```
$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.807 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.807/0.807/0.807/0.000 ms
$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.33
PING 192.168.1.33 (192.168.1.33) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.33: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.365 ms

--- 192.168.1.33 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.365/0.365/0.365/0.000 ms
```

The VM gets an IP address from `dnsmasq` and it can ping the host machine on both the bridge and the physical address:

```
root@archiso ~ # ping -c 1 172.20.0.1                                                                                                                       
PING 172.20.0.1 (172.20.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.20.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms

--- 172.20.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.072/0.072/0.072/0.000 ms
root@archiso ~ # ping -c 1 192.168.1.53                                                                                                                     
PING 192.168.1.53 (192.168.1.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.150 ms

--- 192.168.1.53 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.150/0.150/0.150/0.000 ms
```

Yet, when I try to ping devices on the network, that results in packet loss:

```
root@archiso ~ # ping -c 1 192.168.1.1                                                                                                                      
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

1 root@archiso ~ # ping -c 1 192.168.1.33                                                                                                                   
PING 192.168.1.33 (192.168.1.33) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.33 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Iptables on the host and the VM are both empty:

```
$ sudo !!
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

On the host, I can see the pings arriving from the VM and going out the network, and even see them being returned by the raspberry pi, but I can't see them being arriving back to my laptop:

```
# On the laptop
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s25 -qtln icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
IP 172.20.0.121 > 192.168.1.33: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1, length 64


# On the raspberry pi
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -qtln icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
IP 172.20.0.121 > 192.168.1.33: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1, length 64
IP 192.168.1.33 > 172.20.0.121: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 1, length 64
```

Googling this has led me to try disabling `rp_filter` on all interfaces involved, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Am I overlooking something obvious in my configuration? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A minute after posting this question, it struck me: the other devices don't know how to route packets to my bridge, the don't know that network. I have to use NAT to translate the pings as if they're coming from my laptop's IP address.

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -j MASQUERADE`